# Change startpage on Windows Phone / PhoneGap 1.7

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I'd like to load a different HTML file than the index.html on startup in my PhoneGap 1.7 project for Windows Phone. Unfortunately I can't seem to find where I can change that. Any help?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your MainPage.xaml.cs contains the MainPage constructor. Within this constructor you need to change the startPageUri property of the PGView object as follows:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.PGView.StartPageUri = new Uri("/app/www/test.html", UriKind.Relative);
        this.PGView.Loaded += GapBrowser_Loaded;
    }
```

As you can see I've created a new Uri pointing to a file called test.html in the www directory. Change this string to whatever value you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Open **WMAppManifest.xml** file, look for the tag  and then  and change the attribute NavigationPage to the page you want to navigation when the application starts.